# Native Android studio terminal Error : Could not find class file

Tags: android

Could not find class file for 'com.example.sample.MainActivity' in android studio terminal

Here is my terminal command:

```
E:\Ari\Check\myapplication\src\main\java>javah -d jni -classpath D:/arigarasuthan/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-24/android.jar;D:/arigarasuthan/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;D:/arigarasuthan/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar;../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/ com.example.ari.myapplication.nftBookActivity
```

Error: `Could not find class file for 'com.example.sample.myapplication.MainActivity'.`

Comment: did you import project from eclipse to android studio?

Comment: yes i imported project from eclipse to android stduio

Comment: ok I am giving you solution in answer.

Comment: ok thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer not solved your problem, just check if you had imported support v7 / v4 library in gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running javac first? You will need to compile your java code into a class file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I imported project from eclipse to android studio,
same error occurred. And the following mechanism solved my problem.

Right click on the project -> Properties-> Java Build Path -> Order and Export Tab and select your private libraries. 
then clean your project and rebuild.

This may help you.